# intl-tel-input trigger the 'countrychange' event when setting the same country

Tags: angular, intl-tel-input

I am using intl-tel-input plugin in Angular. I've got the parent component with FormGroup containing `phoneNumber` and `countryCode` properties. I am passing down those properties as form controls to the child. The child component is using the intl-tel-input plugin, the code looks like that

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.iti = intlTelInput(this.input.input.nativeElement, {
    utilsScript: '../../assets/js/phone-utils.js',
    preferredCountries: this.preferredCountries
  })
  this.input.nativeElement.addEventListener('countrychange', () => {
    // set a value in the parent
    this.countryCodeControl.setValue(this.iti.getSelectedCountryData().dialCode)
  })
}
```

I want the `countrychange` event to be triggered at the beginning so I can set the `countryCode` in the parent's form group to the first one on the list. The first country on my list is Germany and if I add `this.iti.setCountry('de')` after initialization, the event is not triggered because this country is already selected in dropdown. I'd have to do something like this

```
this.iti.setCountry('at')  // change the initial country
this.iti.setCountry('de')  // set the initial country once again
```

My question is, can I somehow trigger the `countrychange` event even if I'm trying to set the country that is already selected?